# Query was working in MYSQL but not MYSQLI

Tags: mysql

My query was working in MYSQL but not in MYSQLI.

I'm selecting students that have done the pre AND post test.

```
 SELECT 
  studid as Username, 
  prepoints as 'Fitness Assessment Points Grade', 
  end AS 'End-of-Line Indicator' 
 FROM 
  fittest, points 
 WHERE
  YEAR(submitted) = '2017' 
  AND semester = 'summer2' 
 GROUP BY studid
 HAVING 
  (MAX(prepost = 'pre' ) + MAX(prepost = 'post')) = 2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT prepost) = 2
```

Any ideas what changes need to be made to get it working again?

Here is some sample data:

```
 CREATE TABLE `fittest` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `submitted`
 datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `studid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `semester` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `instructor` varchar(30)
 DEFAULT NULL,   `course` enum('PHED 1164') DEFAULT NULL,   `section`
 enum('5001','5003','5005','5007','5009','5011','5013','5015','5017','5019','5021','5023','5025','5027','5029','5031','5033','5035','5037','5039','5041','5043','5045','5047','5049','5051','5053','5055','5057','5059','5061','5063','5065','5067','5069')
 DEFAULT NULL,   `age` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `gender`
 enum('m','f') DEFAULT NULL,   `ethnicity` enum('Hispanic','African
 American','Asian','White-Non Hispanic','Other') DEFAULT NULL,  
 `height` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,   `weight` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `flexibility` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,   `crunches` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `pushups` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,   `treadtimemin` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `treadtimesec` int(2) NOT NULL,   `treadhr` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `prepost` enum('pre','post') NOT NULL,   `end` char(1) NOT NULL
 DEFAULT '#' ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 INSERT INTO `fittest` (`id`, `submitted`, `studid`, `semester`,
 `instructor`, `course`, `section`, `age`, `gender`, `ethnicity`,
 `height`, `weight`, `flexibility`, `crunches`, `pushups`,
 `treadtimemin`, `treadtimesec`, `treadhr`, `prepost`, `end`) VALUES
 (17, '2017-01-02 21:55:33', 'slacker', 'spring', 'Tim', 'PHED 1164',
 '5001', '32', 'm', NULL, '69.5', 155, NULL, 29, 34, 22, 15, 76, 'pre',
 '#'), (16, '2017-01-02 21:31:34', 'bfun', 'spring', 'Tim', 'PHED
 1164', '5001', '32', 'm', NULL, '69.5', 122, NULL, 37, 36, 18, 14, 76,
 'post', '#'), (15, '2017-01-02 21:31:09', 'bfun', 'spring', 'Tim',
 'PHED 1164', '5001', '32', 'm', NULL, '69.5', 129, NULL, 21, 20, 23,
 14, 76, 'pre', '#'),
```

Comment: If your height field is `CHAR(4)` I'm really worried. Does that contain values like `6'2"`? It's generally best to express something in a single unit, like inches or mm. Also try and avoid using MyISAM in new applications, InnoDB is vastly better.

Comment: `mysqli` is just an interface to MySQL, same as PDO. It's not clear what's wrong here, you haven't explained what, if any errors you're getting. "Not working" is one of the least useful diagnostics you can possibly give.

Comment: The height contains values like "69.5" for inches.

Comment: I just figured out the issue isn't with the query. It was with the input. All the input had post for the prepost value so there were no results that were showing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For fractional values, use something like `DECIMAL(4,1)`. It's much better from a computational point of view and helps eliminate garbage data like `5ft` which could be erroneously interpreted as five inches.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the issue isn't with the query. It was with the input. All the input had post for the prepost value so there were no results that were showing. Thanks for your help.